# Pipe string to a command with multiple read prompts

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe, echo, stdin

How can I pipe a string to a command with multiple read prompts in OS X?

I am running a command for a Parallels VM to enable a password which prompts for multiple values (without running a secondary command).

Ex:

```
$ prlctl set "VM" --password-to-edit
Please enter a new password:
Please verify password:
```

I would like to pipe the password string to both read prompts. I have tried the following but the string is not passed to the second read prompt.

```
echo 'password' | prlctl set "VM" --password-to-edit
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the utility only wants a password multiple times use this:

```
yes 'password' | prlctl set "VM" --password-to-edit
```

`yes` is just prints the string repeatedly until killed.

Comment: The "yes" command worked as expected, thanks for the quick answer!